# Encoding UTF-8 using JAXB Marshaller in SOAPMessage replaces < with &lt;

Tags: java, soap, utf-8, jaxb, marshalling

Currently I'm working on a project with very special needs using CXF and the javax.xml.soap libraries.

What I'm trying to achieve is: I have a notification message of type `org.oasis_open.docs.wsn.b_2.Notify`. To send the content of this notification to a logging service, I'm trying to embed this `Notify` into a `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage` with custom headers, using the JAXB marshaller.

Therefore I'm doing the following:

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "utf-8");

//edit header
SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
header.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", "http://example.org/");

SOAPElement customElement = header.addChildElement("SomeTag","example");
customElement.setTextContent("Test");

//edit body
SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

//marshal Notify 
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Notify.class).createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "utf-8");
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration",Boolean.FALSE);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(notify, sw);

body.setTextContent(sw.toString());
```

To send the message I'm using the following

```
//create a connection to the logging endpoint
URL endpoint = new URL(localhost:19001/services/logging/);
SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance()
    .createConnection();

//send the message to the logger
connection.call(soapMessage, endpoint);
```

When printing out the message using `System.out.println(body.getTextContent());` in my code I get the output correctly displayed (for example `<ns2:NotificationMessage>`). But at the logger we receive something like this:

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
[...]
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  &lt;ns2:Notify"&gt;
    &lt;ns2:NotificationMessage&gt;
     [...]
    &lt;/ns2:NotificationMessage&gt;
  &lt;/ns2:Notify&gt;
</soapenv:Body>
```

when reading the message like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMessage.writeTo(os);
String str = new String(os.toByteArray(), "utf-8");
```

Does anyone have an idea, why the `<` and `>` in the body are replaced although I set the JAXB marshaller to use UTF-8? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

Update "Workaround"

Thanks to Boris The Spider - Until i find the time (and willpower) to correct my code I'm using the following workaround -> Parse the SOAPMessage into a byte-Array and create a String from this using the UTF-8 encoding. On this String I use the `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(String)`function from `org.apache.commons.lang3` and then create a new SOAPMessage from that "un-escaped" String.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMessage.writeTo(os);
String str = new String(os.toByteArray(), "utf-8");
str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(str);

// create a "new" SOAPMessage from unescaped String
soapMessage = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), 
new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));
```

Comment: `body.setTextContent`! `<` is **not allowed** in XML. From [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/): "_The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters._"

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you!